# Extending PHPs echo?

Tags: php, cakephp, echo, sanitization, strip-tags

Is it possible to extend the PHP `echo` so that I can run some extra processing code on every string being displayed? I need a way to sanitize all outputs and don't want to have to call `strip_tags` on every display manually.

Comment: Why can't you write your own function, say `strip_echo`?

Comment: There is a lot of code that uses echo in many, many parts of the code, and I don't want to have to go and manually change them.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182743/can-i-override-the-php-built-in-function-echo

Comment: echo is a language construct, it's not a function, so it can't be extended

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change the behaviour of `echo` but you could make use php's [output buffering functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) (see the callbacks). However, this seems like overkill. As casablance suggested: create a function.

Answer (score 2):

chustar,

write your own class with static methods and put it in app/libs.

Edit0: You are a programmer, write the code that changes the code.

Answer (score 0):

@chutstar, If you're on Linux, you can use **sed** to find and replace all 'echo' with 'strip_echo' in the .php files in a directory, recursively.

Below is how Zend framework replaced all 'require_once' with '//require_once', EXCEPT for 'require_once' that appears in file Loader/Autoloader.php or Application.pp

```
#!/bin/sh
#  cd path/to/ZendFramework/library
# replace all 'require_once' with '//require_once' , and skip Autoloader.php & Application.php
 find . -name '*.php' -not -wholename '*/Loader/Autoloader.php' -not -wholename '*/Application.php' -print0 | xargs -0 sed --regexp-extended --in-place 's/(require_once)/\/\/ \1/g'
```

So **YOUR** script should be

```
#!/bin/sh
# replace all 'echo' with 'strip_echo'
#  cd path/to/ZendFramework/library
 find . -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 sed --regexp-extended --in-place 's/echo/strip_echo/g'
```

I tested and it works. There might be unexpected replaces that you should check though, for example when 'echo' is accidentally part of some other function names or variables, etc..