# Is it possible to create a function in PHP called "echo"?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I override the PHP built-in function echo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182743/can-i-override-the-php-built-in-function-echo)

In languages such as Python, "echo" is not a language construct. Is it possible to shadow the built-in "echo" construct in PHP and implement a function like this:

```
function echo($value) {
    return $value;
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or '('
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182743/can-i-override-the-php-built-in-function-echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182743/can-i-override-the-php-built-in-function-echo)

Comment: no.  You cannot.  Simply.  You could create _echo though.

Comment: well there you go, the answer is no. keep in mind that you can use `echo` like a function though, i.e., `echo('cheese')`. if you need a return value, `print('x')` will return `1`.

Comment: people usually just create wrapper functions for this sort of thing.  what do you plan to us it for and have you already considered a wrapper function?

Comment: I'm testing a cross-language RPC library and want to echo things back to the caller. A Python server can implement echo but a PHP server cannot. Hence, need to choose a different function name that is compatible everywhere.

Comment: If you implement some variant of RPC, then just use a function name map. You're not supposed to accept *any* incoming function name plainly anyway. Also [`rename_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php).

Comment: now why would you want to do that really?

Comment: in your system, how is python interfacing with php?

Comment: Why do you need to use the same name in PHP as you use in Python?

Comment: This is my RPC library: https://github.com/nfarring/redisrpc. Either the client or server can be written in PHP, Python, or Ruby, and hopefully other languages if I can find the time. But if PHP doesn't allow a function called "echo", then a client written in a different language will be incompatible with a PHP server. I guess the same problem would happen in Python if I wanted to make a function called "pass". Not a huge deal really.