# Can I redirect all PRINT and ECHO output to a PHP function?

Tags: php, stdout

I've inherited some ancient code to paw through and figure out what's happening.  Scattered throughout the spaghetti code are hundreds of echos and prints that are nearly impossible to follow.

I've been researching and googling using variations of STDOUT, but can't find anything that doesn't talk about using and alternative to PRINT/ECHO.

I'm looking for a way to effectively *replace* the PHP Echo/Print with my own function called something like "MyEcho" that will interrogate/log what's printing from where and when.

Is there a way to do this, or must I write the function, and replace all print/echo used throughout the code?

Comment: I think you can override the system `echo`/`print` function; but someone else will need to reinforce/reject this idea.

Comment: `echo` is a language construct, not a function, so you cannot override it. You could use output buffering to prevent the output being sent to the browser until you want it to, but that does not help you if you want to monitor when what is echoed.

Comment: Do you need to handle each print/echo separately? If not, you could use ouput buffering and handle the complete output after running the old code.

Comment: I think in this situation you just need a good IDE and replace all the echoes/prints. In my case I use coda2 on OSX and it allows me to find and replace through the code using regex's, look for something similar. replacing/deleting the old stuff might save you time in the end in a lot of situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the manual on echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) states, its not realy a function but a language construct and therefor you cannot override it like you can with system function. (using namespace)

I think your best bet would be to simple use something like [ecobyte replace text](http://www.ecobyte.com/replacetext/) to replace `echo` and `print` with something else.

Just keep in mind that you can run into problems because parentheses are not required for `echo` and `print` but for your function they are. Also echo can allow multiple parameters using a `,`, which could also break your own method.

I think there is not much left to do then a replace all and hope for the best or do it manually.

Comment: This is what I'm up against/afraid of....zero consistency in use/syntax, so the question was really a "Hail Mary" hoping there was some PHP sorcery somewhere that would help.

Comment: You could always alter the PHP source and run your own compiled version :) But regular expression replacing all `print(.*);` and `echo(.*);` with `myprint($1);` should work in 99% of the cases as even with multiple variables for `echo` it will work (your function will simply get multiple parameters) and also double parentheses dont matter.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [output control functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), such as `ob_start()`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that directly overloading echo may not be possible, but [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182743/can-i-override-the-php-built-in-function-echo) may have some leads for you.

You could do a bulk search/replace where you replace `echo` with `echo __FILE__ , __LINE__ ,`